# If Product of Sets is Connected Are the Sets Connected Themselves?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

I am working through a real analysis book and am not sure about how to prove this problem rigorously.

> Suppose we have $A\times B$ is a connected set. Does this imply that $A$ and $B$ (both nonempty) are connected?

I heavily suspect that they do not both have to be, but am having trouble proving this rigorously. I did already prove the other direction that if $A$ and $B$ are connected then $A\times B$ must be.

Comment: Projection maps are continuous and continuous images of connected sets are connected.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Not sure if I'm misunderstanding your response but the product of A and B is connected, as the given.

Comment: @AyushTibrewal: My response was to **Devil’s Staircase**’s erroneous example, not to your question.

Comment: @bof fixed to clarify that A and B are nonempty. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah sorry, that comment was deleted so I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: They don't have to be nonempty. The empty set is connected. And even if for whatever reasons you like to consider it as non-connected, then it follows from the connectedness of $A\times B$ that both $A$ and $B$ are nonempty (since if one of them is empty, then the product is empty as well).

Comment: @Cronus It is essential that they are connected unless you regard the empty set as non-connected. Take any non-connected $A \ne \emptyset$ and $B = \emptyset$. Then $A \times B = \emptyset$.

Comment: @PaulFrost You are correct, my mistake.